# Insert new element to XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a program that inserts a new lesson to a course XML. Here is the XML file:

```
Course.xml

<Courses>

   <Course>
      <Name>ABC course</Name>
      <Lessons>
         <Lesson>
           <Lesson_name>Learn ABC!</Lesson_name>
           <Lesson_date>XX/XX/XXXX</Lesson_date>
         </Lesson>


        'WANT TO ADD A LESSON HERE!!!


      </Lessons>
   </Course>

   <Course>
      <Name>DEF Course</Name>
      <Lesson>
        <Lesson_name>Learn DEF!</Lesson_name>
        <Lesson_date>XX/XX/XXXX</Lesson_date>
      </Lesson>
   </Course>

</Courses>
```

I would want to insert a lesson with all those nodes such as `Lesson`, `Lesson_date`, `Lesson_name` etc. without affecting the existing lessons and other elements. Is there any simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.Load("Course.xml")

Dim courseName = "ABC course"
With xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Courses/Course[Name = '" & courseName & "']/Lessons").CreateNavigator().AppendChild()
    .WriteStartElement("Lesson")
    .WriteElementString("Lesson_name", "Learn something else!")
    .WriteElementString("Lesson_date", "YY/YY/YYYY")
    .WriteEndElement()
    .Close()
End With
```

If you want to modify the actual file, you could use `xmlDoc.Save()` after that.

Comment: Thank you for replying! However just wondering how do i select inserting to specific course? =p

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Shall try it out later... this bugged me a while already /.\

Answer (score 1):

By using the **[DataSet.ReadXml Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** you can do this. Change the values in Dataset table and use **[DataSet.WriteXml Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).**

Comment: Can you give me some examples? =] Thanks for the quick reply XD